# How to "fill" some parts only from the total number of GridView items?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

I have this problem where I wanted to fill some parts only of the GridView depending on the number I give to it. Here's the image:

[image]

If I give 3 only out of 8, 3 of the `GridView` items should be highlighted. **Note that 8 is fixed!** I have all the code and the custom adapter, I'm confused on which part do I check and give the `GridView` 3 of them should only be highlighted.

Here's where I set the custom adapter in my activity:

> ```
>     Integer[] lessons = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
>     CustomAdapter gridViewAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.item_lessons, lessons);
>     gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
> ```

My CustomAdapter:

> ```
>   @Override
>     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>         View row = convertView;
>         ViewHolder holder = null;
>         if (row == null) {
>             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
>             row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
>             holder = new ViewHolder();
>             holder.tvLessons = (TextView) row
>                     .findViewById(R.id.lesson_module);
>             row.setTag(holder);
>         } else {
>             holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
>         } holder.tvLessons.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_lesson_filled);
>         return row;
>     }
>     public class ViewHolder {
>         public TextView tvLessons;
>     }
> ```

Comment: can you explain a bit please.. im confused

Comment: If I give the `GridView` for example a value of 3, like in the image, 3 `GridView` items should be filled with blue. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   @Override
>     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>         View row = convertView;
>         ViewHolder holder = null;
>         if (row == null) {
>             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
>             row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
>             holder = new ViewHolder();
>             holder.tvLessons = (TextView) row
>                     .findViewById(R.id.lesson_module);
>             row.setTag(holder);
>         } else {
>             holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
>         } holder.tvLessons.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_lesson_filled);
>         if(position <= <yourNumber i.e 3>)
>            holder.tvLesson.setBackgroundColor(Color.Blue);
>         return row;
>     }
>     public class ViewHolder {
>         public TextView tvLessons;
>     }
> ```

let me know if you have any problem implementing it
Enjoy...